# configured directory for incoming file does not exist

Tags: command-line, hostname

When I boot Ubuntu from Odroid, this message always appears:

[image]

I change hostname and other, and I use `usermod -d` to change home directory, but I don't know why that message appears. When I use a terminal it always says:

```
odroid@odroid$
```

But after change it says:

```
JARVIS@JARVIS:/home/JARVIS$
```

why?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`?

Comment: JARVIS@JARVIS:/home/JARVIS$ cat /etc/lsb-release         

    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04  

    DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
 i dont know how to make this in code. sry

Answer (score 16):

You can get the path with

```
gsettings get org.blueman.transfer shared-path
```

and change it with (for instance):

```
gsettings set org.blueman.transfer shared-path '/home/toto'
```

Answer (score 6):

Selecting a new /Downloads/ folder in Blueman fixed the issue for me.

You can do it by opening Blueman Services (open Terminal and type `blueman-services`). There, under 'Transfer Settings', select a new folder as 'Incoming Folder' (I just selected /newUsername/Downloads/ as mine).

I apologize for the later answer, but as I had the same issue after I changed my host and user name, and there is no solving answer to this topic, I decided to post what removed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, this command:

```
gsettings set org.blueman.transfer shared-path '/home/your_user_name/Downloads'
```

solved the problem.

Of course instead of `/home/your_user_name/Downloads`, you can insert any other name of an existing folder.